# RAID1 for cloning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, raid

I understand that RAID should not be used for backups but what about using it to create backups on  physical level?
I have a setup of regular rsync backups from all the network to one server. Once a week, all the backups are copied to an external HDD (straightforward with dd) and the HDD is carefully carried home, to prevent loss of data in case something happens with the server room.

Now, would it be a good idea to have a RAID1 array of two or more disks and instead of copying the data - just switch the disk with another one and rebuild the array?
Will it be a problem to restore the data from the extracted disk afterwards?

Comment: What advantage do you hope to get with this?

Comment: I'd be worried about the possibility the RAID might end up reading outdated data from the disk which has been out of the RAID for a while and then came back.

Comment: @SvW Well, I won't need to stop the services to clone the disk, as it is done now, but have everything backed up 'on the go'.

Comment: What makes you think you won't need to stop the services to clone the disc with this new plan?

Comment: I don't see why you are cloning the disks instead of just copying files.

Comment: If your data is on some LVM volumes, wouldn't a LVM snapshort address your needs?

Comment: @MadHatter Because everything mirrors on the other disk the moment it is written on the disk. Although if there's a backup in progress, it's gonna get corrupted when the disk is removed. Yeah, that wasn't very bright of me, thanks

Comment: @SvW because it proved to be much faster, almost 3 times faster than copying, with the downside that HDDs wear out faster, but this is not a problem

Comment: @tonioc The data is not on LVMs, good idea though. Still, I find LVMs kinda unreliable when it comes to backing up crucial stuff

Comment: What is the filesystem in use? Are you using a hardware raid controller?

Comment: @peter-horvath you shouldn't have deleted your comment, I actually found it very inspiring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have worked at a site where this was an official procedure for cloning one very important Solaris machine.  The caveats are:

1. The filesystem will be dirty if this is done while the machine is in use.  You will need to quiesce the file systems if the removed RAID disc isn't to be a very blurry snapshot, and under UNIX, this generally means shutting the machine down briefly (which is what we did) or accepting that you'll have to `fsck` the removed disc as soon as you boot off it, and that this may involve losing some data.
2. The removed disc needs to be placed into a chassis that is identical in all respects except where differences are completely unavoidable (eg, MAC addresses of NICs).  Even then, some cleanup work will be needed to allow the removed HDD to boot, and be resynced to a pair in the new chassis (we had a formal procedure for this).
3. The production machine needs to be given a **clean** disc on which to resync its RAID as soon as it's brought back up.

It was some years ago, and I forget exactly why this particular machine was cloned in this way, although at the time I thought the reasons sound.  I still feel this isn't a great technique for cloning, although it works for that, and it's a **terrible** technique for backups - it's **very much** more expensive than just doing proper backups.

Comment: Losing data due to running `fsck` shouldn't happen on any properly designed file system.

Comment: You may be right, but UNIX UFS probably doesn't count as one of those.

Comment: Reason #1 alone is enough to call it a terrible technique. Thanks!